# value is being read in as column title in mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to add data to a mysql database. Can someone explain why the query seems to be treating `temp` as a column instead of the string value it is supposed to be?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/PiControl $ python writedb.py
rollback:  (1054, "Unknown column 'temp' in 'field list'")
done
```

my table

```
mysql> select * from logs;
+----+--------+---------+------+
| id | sensor | reading | time |
+----+--------+---------+------+
|  1 | temp   |    NULL | NULL |
|  2 | NULL   |   69.69 | NULL |
|  3 | NULL   |   69.69 | NULL |
|  4 | NULL   | 1234.56 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL   | 1234.56 | NULL |
|  6 | NULL   | 1234.56 | NULL |
|  7 | temp   |     123 | NULL |
|  8 | temp   |      20 | NULL |
+----+--------+---------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The script:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",user="xx",passwd="yy",db="homelog")
x = conn.cursor()

try:
   x.execute("INSERT INTO `logs` (`sensor`,`reading`) VALUES (`temp`,`4242`)")
   #print x.execute("SELECT * FROM logs") #returns number of rows in table for some reason
   conn.commit()
except Exception, e:
   print 'rollback: ',e
   conn.rollback()

conn.close()
print "done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parameterizing your query avoiding using backticks for column values:

```
sensor = "temp"
reading = 4242
x.execute("INSERT INTO `logs` (`sensor`,`reading`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (sensor, reading))
```

> print x.execute("SELECT * FROM logs") #returns number of rows in table for some reason

You need to *fetch all the matching records* from the cursor after executing:

```
sensor = "temp"
reading = 4242
x.execute("INSERT INTO `logs` (`sensor`,`reading`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (sensor, reading))
conn.commit()

x.execute("SELECT * FROM logs")
print(x.fetchall())
```

Comment: That worked perfectly... any idea why the backticks didnt work? (waiting 2 minutes to accept your answer)

Comment: @Rilcon42 I am really not sure. I was always under the impression that backticks would not hurt and are needed when there are special characters inside an identifier name. I guess this is MySQLdb specific issue. Just to check, can you try the insert query with the backticks in the mysql console? Thanks.

Comment: That works in console.... I started there and then moved to python where it failed.... wierd